# MVC - ajax posting model to controller is epic failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Here's what I'm trying to do:

My viewmodel:

```
public class Inputs
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
public class UserViewModel { }
public class LearnerSupportViewModel
{
    public LearnerSupportViewModel()
    {
        Inputs = new Inputs();
        SearchRecords = new List<UserViewModel>();
        UserRecords = new List<UserViewModel>();
    }
    public Inputs Inputs { get; set; }
    public IList<UserViewModel> SearchRecords { get; set; }
    public IList<UserViewModel> UserRecords { get; set; }
}
```

my ajax:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function (evt) {
    // Prevent the button from triggering a form submission.
    evt.preventDefault();

    //var model = JSON.stringify({ model: form }, null);
    $.extend(FormSerializer.patterns, {
        validate: /^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(?:\.[a-z0-9_]+)*(?:\[\])?$/i
    });
    var model = $('form#supportForm').serializeJSON();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Learner/Search',
        type: "GET",
        data: model,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#supportForm').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

the contents of model on posting:

```
"{\"Inputs\":{\"UserName\":\"user\",\"FirstName\":\"first\",\"LastName\":\"last\",\"EmailAddress\":\"email\",\"City\":\"city\",\"State\":\"state\",\"ZipCode\":\"zip\",\"Country\":\"0\"}}"
```

But when I look at the controller action

```
public ActionResult Search(LearnerSupportViewModel model)
```

all the properties of model.Inputs are null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you open up Fiddler or your browser's dev tools and include the actual HTTP GET request being made?  I think the problem is that you are serializing to JSON and then sending that in an HTTP GET.

Comment: That was it.  Dang REST mentality - had to change the ajax & action methods to POST.

Answer (score 0):

Your **data** property of ajax looks not fine to me.

change your **data** property to this:

```
data:{ model : model},
```

Also change type from `GET` to `POST` and add **HttpPost** attribute on your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(LearnerSupportViewModel model)
```

your ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Search","Learner")',
        type: "POST",
        data: 
        {
         model : model
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#supportForm').html(data);
        }
    });
```